# Magento REST API keeps returning "signature_invalid" error

Tags: rest, api, magento, oauth, postman

I'm trying to use the Firefox Rest client extension to test out my Magento REST API. I followed this guide but I keep getting the "signature_invalid" error when making the final request to receive the access token.

Guide: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/testing_rest_resources.html

The URL I use for the final request is:

http://mymagento/oauth/token?oauth_callback=http://httpbin.org/get&oauth_token=99e48f7d46d3a2f8fef704865fe2f4e4&oauth_secret=eda948ee46250f335146f6f4c5f7d622&oauth_verifier=1d977f0b96f3ae07fff515c590ec6709

And these are the readers:

```
OAuth oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Fhttpbin.org%2Fget",
oauth_token="99e48f7d46d3a2f8fef704865fe2f4e4",
oauth_secret="eda948ee46250f335146f6f4c5f7d622",
oauth_verifier="1d977f0b96f3ae07fff515c590ec6709",
oauth_nonce="OmOzMMy2Z60m5sV", oauth_timestamp="1495611445",
oauth_consumer_key="abc77ce5a53e67333af04807dea1356b",
oauth_signature="tE6xzRXZIc4BPQ3Dxc80ddoitLg%3D"
```

The nonce, timestamp and signature are automaticly refreshed each request.

I'm using Magento CE 1.9.2.2.
I have also tried Postman, but that tool gives me a nonce_used error with every request, even though it's automaticly refreshed... Permissions are correctly set up as explained here: http://inchoo.net/magento/configure-magento-rest-and-oauth-settings/

Everything goes fine using the Rest client extension untill the final request where I want to receive the access token.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution... The local browser had cached the oauth responses...